# Digital Logic: What are "hamming code" and "Binary code" state machines?

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop, state-machines

I'm asked to draw the circuit for a state machine in one hot, hamming code and binary code models. I know what is one hot state machine, but i'm not sure what are the other 2. Google also didn't help. Any ideas?

Comment: examine the work of Richard Hamming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a state machine with N states, there are a number of different ways to encode those states as binary logic.

- **One-hot** encoding assigns one FF to each state, so it requires N FFs. Only one FF has the value 1 (is "hot") at a time. If at any time, more than one FF is 1, that's an error.
- **Binary** encoding assigns sequential integers to the states, and they get encoded on \$\lceil\log_2 N\rceil\$ FFs as unsigned binary numbers.
- **Hamming** encoding is similar to binary encoding, except that enough additional FFs are added so that the state assignments are Hamming codes that are capable of correcting single-bit errors and detecting double-bit errors. An error detector monitoring the state values can determine that an error has occurred and correct it. If the binary encoding requires \$M = \lceil\log_2 N\rceil\$ FFs, then the Hamming encoding requires an additional \$\lceil\log_2 M\rceil + 1\$ FFs.

Comment: **Addendum:**
Vendors of synthesis software (Xilinx Vivado, Intel Quartus, Synopsys Simplify, ...) are offering additional encodings like gray code, sequential, ... These codes depend on the number of states and the layout of the state transition graph. Tools might explore different encodings to choose the "best" encoding with regards to area (resources) and speed (timing).